What is the correct way of initializing keys in PKWARE encryption?
According to APPNOTE Chapter 6.1.4, the following is the correct way of initializing keys:
    Key(0) <- 305419896
    Key(1) <- 591751049
    Key(2) <- 878082192

    loop for i <- 0 to length(password)-1
        update_keys(password(i))
    end loop

    Where update_keys() is defined as:

    update_keys(char):
      Key(0) <- crc32(key(0),char)
      Key(1) <- Key(1) + (Key(0) & 000000ffH)
      Key(1) <- Key(1) * 134775813 + 1
      Key(2) <- crc32(key(2),key(1) >> 24)
    end update_keys

Which means if my password is 12345678 then the value of Keys should always be the same accross all applications but i got them different and i wonder which one is correct because i see no difference in their code.
Here is the Outputs:
45b9d237 daacd099 c58a0384
E093805D A9A0111B 539482EC

Thank you.
